# COBOL field validation using EXAMINE verb

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have a field in my CICS BMS map as email-id. I want to validate that field for various validations such as it should contain only 1 '@'  character and only 1 '.co.in' or '.com' otherwise user should be prompted to enter a valid email-id.

1. I have tried working on it with `EXAMINE` verb but it is just working for '@' validation. Somehow it is not working for '.co.in' or '.com'. I think, I am going wrong somewhere.
2. Problem is in `EXAMINE` verb I can't use different counter for every field. So I want to know how to validate multiple strings using examine verb.

Comment: Show your code! How can we help you if we have to guess what your code is doing

Comment: `EXAMINE` is an IBM Extension to COBOL 68 (ANS COBOL). If you locate documentation on `EXAMINE` then you'll find why it doesn't work for .co.in or .com. You do need to show your code and confirm which compiler you are using, which is indicated at the top of each page of the compile listing.

Comment: Is EXAMINE even recognized by Enterprise COBOL? I suggest reading up on the correct verb, INSPECT, check your code, and then either come back here and update your question appropriately, or close this question.

Comment: Have a look at [this e-mail address validation](http://www.mvsforums.com/helpboards/viewtopic.php?p=30574&sid=c2814ce3ad549abdd4b2ac70c03df356) in COBOL. You should be able to pattern your validation after this one

Comment: @NealB If `EXAMINE` is working for the full-stop/period, as claimed, then UNSTRING and INSPECT are not going to work :-) I'd suggest not using the code it is bug-ridden. Yes there must be something out there which conforms to the RFC - however, just getting people to type it twice and seeing if it is the same is common...

Comment: @BillWoodger Good point. I forgot that `EXAMINE` and `INSPECT` are mutually exclusive verbs based on compiler versions (at least for IBM). I also agree that editing an e-mail address to verify that it strictly conforms to RFC 5322, 5321 and 3696 is considerably more complex. Also well formed syntax doesn't mean the address itself is valid (exists). Typing twice isn't a great solution either simply because "muscle memory" can lead to typing the same mistake twice (or more) in a row. I've exceeded password attempts more than once because of it. Some things are difficult to foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspect/tallying.  Or write a simple finite state machine subprogram to parse out [A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9].[A-Za-z] from a text field.

Comment: EXAMINE and INSPECT don't exist in the same compiler. EXAMINE is in IBM's COBOL '68, as an Extension, INSPECT is COBOL '74 and is Standard. EXAMINE, TRANSFORM disappeared going from '68 to '74, replaced by INSPECT.

Comment: No need to write a state machine, the C runtime regex functions are callable from Enterprise COBOL.  Possibly not for the faint of heart.